# Problem with earth orbit plot using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to write a code for the orbit of the earth in SI using a symplectic integrator, my attempt is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Set parameters
G = 6.67348e-11
mEar = 5.972e24
mSun = 1.989e30

def earth_orbit(x0, y0, vx0, vy0, N):
    dt = 1/N                    #timestep
    pos_arr = np.zeros((N,2))   #empty array to store position
    vel_arr = np.zeros((N,2))   #empty array to store velocities

    #Initial conditions
#     x0 = x
#     y0 = y
#     vx0 = vx
#     vy0 = vy
    pos_arr[0] = (x0,y0)        #set the intial positions in the array
    vel_arr[0] = (vx0,vy0)      #set the initial velocities in the array

    #Implement Verlet Algorithm
    for k in range (N-1):
        pos_arr[k+1] = pos_arr[k] + vel_arr[k]*dt                       #update positions
        force = -G * mSun * mEar * pos_arr[k+1] / (np.linalg.norm(pos_arr[k+1])**3)   #force calculation 
        vel_arr[k+1] = vel_arr[k] + (force/mEar) * dt                     #update velocities

    #Plot:
    plt.plot(pos_arr, 'go', markersize = 1, label = 'Earth trajectory')
#     plt.plot(0,0,'yo', label = 'Sun positon')                  # yellow marker
#     plt.plot(pos_arr[0],'bo', label = 'Earth initial positon')  # dark blue marker
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.xlabel ('x')
    plt.ylabel ('y')

    return pos_arr, vel_arr

earth_orbit(149.59787e9, 0, 0, 29800, 1000)
```

The output is 2 dots and I can't figure out if this is a unit issue or a calculation issue?

Comment: Note that this is not the Verlet algorithm, but the symplectic Euler algorithm. The difference is that for Leapfrog Verlet you would need to advance `vel_arr[0]` to the velocity at time `dt/2`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Display the trajectory

`pos_arr` contains the `x` and `y` coordinates in its columns. To display the whole trajectory, `plt.plot(pos_arr[:,0], pos_arr[:,1])` can thus be used. I would prefer to use `plt.plot(*pos_arr.T)` as a shorter alternative. The line that displays the trajectory must be replaced by:

```py
plt.plot(*pos_arr.T, 'g', label = 'Earth trajectory')
```

#### Change the timestep

Here the timestep (**in second**) is chosen as `1/N`, where `N` is the number of iterations. So, the total duration of the simulation is equal to `timestep * N = 1 second` ! For `N=1000`, you can instead try with `timestep = 3600*12` (half-day), so that the total duration is a little less than 1.5 years. I suggest passing the `duration` as a parameter of the function `earth_orbit` and then setting `timestep` as `duration / N`.

```py
def earth_orbit(x0, y0, vx0, vy0, N=1000, duration=3.15e7):
    dt = duration / N
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, this is not the Verlet algorithm, but the symplectic Euler algorithm. The difference is in the initialization, but in comparing against a more exact reference solution and with several step sizes, the difference in the orders, 2 vs. 1, will be quite visible.

A short change to the time loop ensuring that the velocities are at the half-time steps as required for Leapfrog Verlet could look like this:

```python
    def force(pos): return -G * mSun * mEar * pos_arr[k+1] / (np.linalg.norm(pos_arr[k+1])**3)   #force calculation 
    pos_arr[0] = (x0,y0)        #set the intial positions in the array
    vel_arr[0] = (vx0,vy0)      #set the initial velocities in the array
    vel_arr[0] += (force(pos_arr[0])/mEar) * (0.5*dt) #correct for velocity at half-time

    #Implement Verlet Algorithm
    for k in range (N-1):
        pos_arr[k+1] = pos_arr[k] + vel_arr[k] * dt                    #update positions
        vel_arr[k+1] = vel_arr[k] + (force(pos_arr[k+1])/mEar) * dt    #update velocities
```